# small solar light plan

Tags: resistors

I am trying to build a solar light for my yard using a 6volt,200ma solar panel and 3-1.2 volt rechargeable batteries. I have 8 red leds in parallel each having its own 33 ohm resistor. I am using a bc547 transistor to switch on at night. The collector attaches to the negative side of the parallel leds/ resistors. The emitter goes to negative between battery and solar negative. there is a resistor from the positive side before the leds to the base. also I have a diode 4007 to block current from going backward when not in charging mode. The problem I have is what size resistor goes to the base of the transistor.Please help

Comment: A schematic would be clearer than a description of your circuit. There's a schematic editor on the site, you can [edit] your question and add it (button in the editor toolbar).

Comment: Add a schematic. How are you detecting when it is dark outside? What wattage? There is a circuit for those garden lights based on YX805, look it up.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Please click on Edit and the schematic symbol and draw what you have. EEs speak in terms of schematic symbols.

Comment: This is sub-optimal for matching batteries to load and also PV to battery voltage.  Would you like to double efficiency of both charger and LED drive?

Answer (score 0):

If you guess that the current gain of the transistor is about 100 then choose a resistor that will yield a base current of at least 1% of the desired collector-emitter current.  I’d go for 2-3% to be sure that the transistor is well saturated.